# Update json and insert in specific postion

Tags: c#

I have an json as:

```
{
    "count":500,
    "type":"table",
    "data1": {
        "name":"test123",
        "comments":"test123",
        "id":"123"      
    },
    "data2":{
        "env":"dev",
        "status":"new"
    }
}
```

I want to update this existing one and add an extra element to the data2 part so that the output is as below:

```
{
    "count":500,
    "type":"table",
    "data1": {
        "name":"test123",
        "comments":"test123",
        "id":"123"      
    },
    "data2":{
        "env":"dev",
        "status":"new",
        "priority":"none"
    }
}
```

See  "priority":"none" been added above.

I tried using data.Insert but this takes in position and the data.

How can I loop through and add this to the data2 part of my object.

Thanks

--Update

```
 public string metaData { get; set; }

 //getting data from db
 var myData = await this.getDataAsync(id);

// myData.metaData contains the above json
```

I am trying to insert another element to above.

I am not sure how to parse and add it to a particular postion with the code I am using

I have read we can deserialize the object and then add it using .Add but again I have my string above which is holding this 
 how can i update this

Comment: There are no arrays here.

Comment: Sorry my bad have updated it

Comment: Still no arrays.

Comment: The question is a bit clearer now. We can see what your start and end points are, but now it's time to show your attempt.

Comment: *I tried using data.Insert but this takes in position and the data.* - might you please [edit] your question to share what you tried that did not work?  It's not even clear how you are deserializing your JSON, are you loading it with `JToken.Parse()` from [tag:json.net] or are you deserializing to some data model?  Or maybe you are using [tag:system.text.json]?

Comment: have updated it, not sure if its still clear. Sorry if I am not able to frame my question correctly

Comment: If that is all, you can simply use `JObject.Parse()` and append a property to the `data2` object. Something like: `var data = JObject.Parse(json); ((JObject)data["data2"]).Property("status").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("priority", "none"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use models with newtonsoft this example might help.

Model contains the additional fields you want. when deserialized in to the model, on existing properties (ones that are nullable) will be null. Then assign as you wish

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {

        static string jsonStr = "{" +
                    "    \"count\":500," +
                    "    \"type\":\"table\"," +
                    "    \"data1\": {" +
                    "        \"name\":\"test123\"," +
                    "        \"comments\":\"test123\"," +
                    "        \"id\":\"123\"      " +
                    "    }," +
                    "    \"data2\":{" +
                    "        \"env\":\"dev\"," +
                    "        \"status\":\"new\"" +
                    "    }" +
                    "}";

        public class Data1
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string comments { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
        }

        public class Data2
        {
            public string env { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }

            // Additional property
            public string priority { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Data1 data1 { get; set; }
            public Data2 data2 { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace Program.jsonStr with your data from awaited context
            RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Program.jsonStr);
            obj.data2.priority = "none";
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`. Parse the json to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), get the `data2` property and add `priority`

```cs
var parsedObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var data2 = parsedObject["data2"];
data2["priority"] = "none";
var result = parsedObject.ToString();
```

You'll get the following output

```
{
  "count": 500,
  "type": "table",
  "data1": {
    "name": "test123",
    "comments": "test123",
    "id": "123"
  },
  "data2": {
    "env": "dev",
    "status": "new",
    "priority": "none"
  }
}
```